# Tabs en angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Como agrego las tab en Angularjs? me di cuenta que al hacerlo de manera normal y al hacer click en una tab me direciona a la pagina principal (la que ordeno cuando no existe una)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo que crear u controlador? como seria eso?

```
<section class="central">
    <ul class="res nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="col">NORMAL</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="rpam">PRIORITARIO</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="#col">
          <div class="contenido" id="contenido1">
            jsjsjs
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="#cal">
          <div class="contenido" id="contenido2">
            ojojo
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Es realmente sencillo. Para que lo comprendas mejor, te pongo un pequeño ejemplo.

**Controlador**

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('TabController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.tab = 1;

    $scope.setTab = function(newTab){
      $scope.tab = newTab;
    };

    $scope.isSet = function(tabNum){
      return $scope.tab === tabNum;
    };
}]);
```

**Vista**

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
   <li ng-class="{ active: isSet(1) }">
     <a href ng-click="setTab(1)">Principal</a>
   </li>
   <li ng-class="{ active: isSet(2) }">
     <a href ng-click="setTab(2)">Ventas</a>
   </li>
   <li ng-class="{ active: isSet(3) }">
     <a href ng-click="setTab(3)">Compras</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Si te fijas hacemos uso de `ng-click`, en donde llamamos al método `setTab` del controlador, pasándole el índice de la pestaña. Como plus, hago uso de `ng-class` para añadir una clase CSS a la pestaña activa en cuanto lo esté.

Ahora, se supone que cada una de estas pestañas renderiza un contenido asociado a ellas. Para esto basta con hacer uso de `ng-show` del mismo modo que lo usamos en las pestañas:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div ng-show="isSet(1)">
    <h1>Principal</h1>
  </div>
  <div ng-show="isSet(2)">
    <h1>Ventas</h1>
  </div>
  <div ng-show="isSet(3)">
    <h1>Compras</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Si hacemos click en la pestaña `Principal`, se mostrará el div con el `<h1>Principal</h1>` y se le añade la clase `active` a la tab.